# IE 7,8: overflow "visible" with float "left" and a fixed width

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Any Idea how to make IE render the following as in FF or Chrome??!!

Firefox and chrome show images under each other.. internet explorer ignores the width and show LI's next to each other

```
 <html>
    <style>
    ul{
      position: relative;
      height: auto;
    }
    li{
      list-style-type: none;
      width: 30px !important;
      display: inline;
      float: left;
      overflow: visible
    }
    img{
      width:100px;
    }
    </style>
    <body>

    <ul>
      <li>
         <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Joker_red_02.svg/220px-Joker_red_02.svg.png" />
      </li>

      <li>
         <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Joker_red_02.svg/220px-Joker_red_02.svg.png" />
      </li>

      <li>
         <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Joker_red_02.svg/220px-Joker_red_02.svg.png" />
      </li>
    </ul>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you please [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) it?

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nYJrd/. Looks the same in IE8 to me.

Comment: The fiddle is rendering with a standards-mode doctype (HTML5). The original question has no doctype. Viewing the code in quirks mode shows the problem.

Comment: @j08691 uh! yes,, IE8 render it as it should be on jsfiddle.. but when I save the code in a separate file and open it, then the images are displayed next to each other... seems the CSS of jsfiddle resets something that is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/nYJrd/2/

```
ul{
    /*position: relative;
    height: auto;*/ /* These lines aren't really doing anything (with the current example). */
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left:-70px; /* This is what makes them overlap. */
}
li.first{ 
    margin-left:0;
}
img{
    width:100px;
}​
```

That is, if you have control over the markup. If you don't, you can use `li + li {}` but that isn't compatible with non CSS3 browsers. The benefit of this approach is that you can animate the margin left on those `li` elements to show portions of the card.

Comment: For an example of the animation I was talking about, see: http://jsfiddle.net/nYJrd/3/